# Woocommerce - change sort order for "allow back-orders?" dropdown - need Allow, but notify customer first

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

In Woocommerce add product page:

Does anyone know a `filter` that would allow me to re-arrange `allow back-orders?` dropdown in admin to make `Allow but notify customer` appear as the first option? This is because 95% of products need to be back-order allowed but change the dropdown from `Do Not Allow` each time a new product is added is significant time loss.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The command return options are returned by the "wc_get_product_backorder_options()" function in /includes/wc-products-functions.php.

You can't override this function, because it is not a function located in a WooCommerce template. It is not located in a PHP class.

So there is no filter to change the order of the options.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you for shedding some light on this, yeah this function does not have any filters which IMO is an oversight even if very, very few people like me would need to change it.